# htaccess file to remove folder, and replace underscores with dashes

Tags: .htaccess

I need to change the following url

```
http://somedomain.com/news/a_sample_news_article.html
```

to

```
http://somedomain.com/post/a-sample-news-article
```

I have this in my htaccess which works, but I am sure it can be improved upon - does anyone have a better solution?

```
RewriteEngine on
# replace underscores
RewriteRule ^(news)/([^_]*)_+(.*)$ /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC,R=302]
# redirect the directory from news to post
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ /post/$1 [R,L]
# remove .html from end of url
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect

- /news/foo_bar

to

- /post/foo-bar

you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect "/news/foo_bar" to "/foo_bar"    
RewriteRule ^news/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R]
#2 replace underscore with hypens
RewriteRule (.*)_(.*) $1-$2 [N,E=uscores:yes]
RewriteCond %{ENV:uscores} yes
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /post/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Many thanks for getting back - works great. In the context of these rules, what's the best way of removing the .html from the original url?