# Url redirection - changing folder, replacing underscores with dashes and removing html extension

Tags: .htaccess

I have an old site where I have underscores and an html extension which I want to redirect in the following way

```
http://example.com/news/this_is_a_test.html -> http://example.com/post/this-is-a-test

http://example.com/portfolio/another_test.html -> http://example.com/project/another-test
```

There are other folders apart from news and portfolio and clearly the final segment of the url has an unknown number of underscores.

Here is the .htaccess I am using at the moment (based on my original question [htaccess file to remove folder, and replace underscores with dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37279141/htaccess-file-to-remove-folder-and-replace-underscores-with-dashes)). It works for the news example, but breaks if I try for portfolio.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect "/news_bar" to "/foo_bar"
RewriteRule ^news/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R]
#2 replace underscore with hypens
RewriteRule (.*)_(.*) $1-$2 [N,E=uscores:yes]
RewriteCond %{ENV:uscores} yes
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /post/$1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule (.*)_(.*) $1-$2 [N,E=uscores:yes]
RewriteCond %{ENV:uscores} yes
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /project/$1 [L,R]

# remove .html from end of url

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a [solution](/questions/36827398/url-redirect-from-to-htaccess/36832224#36832224) for this before, but it is breaking on my current setup (Apache crashes), and so it would be unwise of me to recommend it for your case. (It could be an issue with my setup, but I'd prefer to give you a more straight-forward route.)

This solution involves sending the relevant requests to a PHP file that will do the necessary replacements, and redirect *once* only. Note that your current implementation will send multiple redirect instructions to the browser. This is not only bad from a user experience point of view, but also from an SEO one.

To implement the solution, start by replacing your `.htaccess` directives with this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite news and portfolio links to redirect.php
RewriteRule ^(news|portfolio)/(.+).html /redirect.php [L]
```

Then, create a `redirect.php` file in the same directory as your `.htaccess` file (in this case, your document root), and fill it with this simple replacement method and redirect instruction:

```php
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

# Perform the necessary replacements. The first array contains
# what we're searching for, bit by bit, and the second array
# contains the relevant replacements.
$path = str_replace(
    ['_', '/news/', '/portfolio/', '.html'],
    ['-', '/post/', '/project/',   ''],
$path);

# Now, simply redirect to the new path.
# Change 302 to 301 use a "Moved Permanently" header,
# resulting in browsers and search engines caching
# the redirect.
header("Location: $path", true, 302);
```

Comment: Hi Mike, many thanks for your help. I didn't want to use any PHP but this is certainly an option !!! Do you think it's the optimal solution for this case?

Comment: My original solution would have been more optimal as it's all done before anything is sent to PHP. That said, the amount of resources used is really nothing to be worried about, and this route should be lightning fast on any server. Also consider the fact that I'm not using regular expressions here, which use more resources than simple string replacements.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for getting back - I'm going to use PHP - works fine. Many thanks for you help